# How to manage nested object with React Native State

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to build a water reminder app. I have 4 screens and I am using react-navigation

- Home (that I allow users to increase their amount drink that day and
  display how much water they drunk)
- History (where user's water drinking history is displayed with graph and this is where I need nested object )
- Notifications (where users defining with switch buttons if they
  want to receive notifications    and when to receive)
- Settings (where the user enters age, weight to    determine how much
  they should drink daily). this is the first screen    users see when
  they downloaded the app

I have state in my apps such as drunk, goal etc. Everyday I am setting drunk value to zero that users can start over again.

What I have done is that I have created new state called object and set it to empty object. And I was able to update history state as below with state handler function.

```
  handleHistory = () => {
    let currentDateString = moment().format('DDMMYYYY');
    this.setState(
      {
        history: {
          ...this.state.history,
          date: currentDateString,
          drunk: this.state.drunk,
          goal: this.state.goal,
          progress: this.state.progress,
        },
      });
  };

//this is what I get
Object {
    "date": "20052019",
    "drunk": 136,
    "goal": 82,
    "progress": 1.6585365853658536,
}
```

What i need is that nested object with dates with keys as date

```
history: {
    "20052019": {
        "date": "20052019",
        "drunk": 136,
        "goal": 82,
        "progress": 1.6585365853658536,
    },
    "21052019": {
        "date": "21052019",
        "drunk": 82,
        "goal": 82,
        "progress": 1.0,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically access/create keys using `object[key]`.

```js
handleHistory = () => {
  const currentDateString = moment().format('DDMMYYYY');
  const { history, drunk, goal, progress } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    history: {
      ...history,
      [currentDateString]: {
        ...history[currentDateString],
        date: currentDateString,
        drunk, goal, progress
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: One question @zaytrix I used your solution but I was expecting to keep previous day Object item and new day item is included the current one. However each day my history state includes only one item which is current Date item.

Comment: @sinan I've updated my answer, hopefully it helps your use case